# Template for image with effects and triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I have wpf xaml code as shown below

```
<Image Source="/MyProject;component/Resources/Icons/button_cancel_256.png"
   DockPanel.Dock="Right"
   Margin="0,1,10,1"
   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
   >
<Image.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScaleTransform" 
                    ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" 
                    />
</Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Effect>
       <DropShadowEffect x:Name="ImageGlowEffect"
           BlurRadius="20"
           ShadowDepth="0"
           Color="White">
       </DropShadowEffect>
   </Image.Effect>
<Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageGlowEffect"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                        From="White"
                        To="Red"
                        Duration="0:0:1">
                    </ColorAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageGlowEffect"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                        From="Red"
                        To="White"
                        Duration="0:0:1">
                    </ColorAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                        From="1"
                        To=".9"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                        From="1"
                        To=".9"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                        From=".9"
                        To="1"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                        From=".9"
                        To="1"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Image.Triggers>
```

Now i want to create a style or template so that I can apply this to other images where i can specify the color.

Please help i have not been able to do it after various tries.

Comment: What exatcly was the problem? You might have created style for all these settings

Comment: I need to use these trigger for many images and i need some kind of template/style that i can apply on all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what EvAlex posted, you can dynamically change the colors specific to an Image then use `DynamicResource` and `Opacity` double animation (in place of ColorAnimation) as below...

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}"
           x:Key="DropShadowImageStyle">
         <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform
                    ScaleX="1"
                    ScaleY="1" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect
                    BlurRadius="20"
                    ShadowDepth="0" 
                    Opacity="0"
                    Color="{DynamicResource MyToColor}">
                </DropShadowEffect>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation  
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"
                                From="0"
                                To="1"                                     
                                Duration="0:0:1">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"
                                From="1"
                                To="0"
                                Duration="0:0:1">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                From="1"
                                To=".9"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                From="1"
                                To=".9"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                From=".9"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                From=".9"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="MyImage1.JPG"
           Width="50" Height="50" Margin="5"
           Style="{StaticResource DropShadowImageStyle}">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="MyToColor">Red</Color>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
    <Image Source="MyImage2.JPG"
           Width="50" Height="50" Margin="5"
           Style="{StaticResource DropShadowImageStyle}">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="MyToColor">Blue</Color>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
    <Image Source="MyImage3.JPG"
           Width="50" Height="50" Margin="5"
           Style="{StaticResource DropShadowImageStyle}">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="MyToColor">Orange</Color>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the style - works well. The problem was with `Storyboard.TargetName` property. I just removed it and modified `Storyboard.TargetProperty`. That's why I asked you in a comment what was your problem. It would be much easier for me if you specified additional information from the beginning.

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,10,1"/>
    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="White"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Color"
                            From="White"
                            To="Red"
                            Duration="0:0:1">
                        </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Color"
                            From="Red"
                            To="White"
                            Duration="0:0:1">
                        </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                            From="1"
                            To=".9"
                            Duration="0:0:0.1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                            From="1"
                            To=".9"
                            Duration="0:0:0.1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                            From=".9"
                            To="1"
                            Duration="0:0:0.1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                            From=".9"
                            To="1"
                            Duration="0:0:0.1">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: ThankYou! Its what i am looking for. Also Can you please tell how to pass colors for color animation and effect.

Comment: Pass into style? I think it's not possible. I would consider creating custom control, register DependencyProperties for these settings there, make it's default template include Image and style for it. And then it will be possible to use TemplateBindings there.

Comment: @Vinay / EvAlex, it is possible to achieve what you seek as specified in my solution below...